# Android Java - String Variable inside a String?

Tags: java, android, string

I am looking for a solution to add inside a String URL a variable (Post parameter).

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);    
String my_variable = "test";
private  static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://xxx/comments.php?usernames= my_variable";
```

It should eventually possible with string.format. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Post parameters don't come in url itsef.

Comment: what you want exactly to do ? why you dnt use smth like String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://xxx/comments.php?usernames="+ my_variable;

Comment: i have tried this before but then allways the android app crash after login

Comment: i wanted load a username of sharedpreferences and add this add end of the url to make a query over php /mysql

Comment: Do what @MariaGheorghe suggested. That's how its done. If your app is crashing then issue must be something else. Put your logcat error trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Java String formatting like below:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);    
String my_variable = "test";
private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = 
    String.format("http://xxx/comments.php?usernames=%s", my_variable);
```

Here is reference for Formatting Strings:
http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/use-string-format-java-string-output

Answer (score 3):

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);    
String my_variable = "test";
private  static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://xxx/comments.php?usernames= "+my_variable;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code `my_variable` is a string not variable because you using it as string inside of double quotes`("")`

```
 private  static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL =
 "http://xxx/comments.php?usernames= my_variable";
```

If you are using variable with string you have to concatenate string with variable

```
private  static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL =
     "http://xxx/comments.php?usernames="+my_variable;
```

If you want to format your string use `String` class api

> static String     format(String format, Object... args)
>   Formats the supplied objects using the specified message format pattern.

```
private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = 
    String.format("http://xxx/comments.php?usernames=%s", my_variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

java.text.MessageFormat should work for you - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/MessageFormat.html